# Duvidas do python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação

Sou novo no python, e estou querendo fazer um sistema, onde você preenche um questionário, e consequentemente ele já imprima em html para apenas colar no forúm. O que eu montei foi o seguinte:

```
from datetime import datetime

now=datetime.now()

ano=now.year

mes=now.month

dia=now.day

aprovados=input('Digite o(s) nick(s) do(s) aprovado(s): ')

naprovados=int(input('Digite o número de aprovados: '))

reprovados=input('Digite o nome do(s) aluno(s) reprovado(s): ')

nreprovados=int(input('Digite o número de alunos reprovados: '))

nalunos=naprovados + nreprovados

inicio=input('Digite o horário do início da aula: ')

termino=input('Digite o horário do término da aula:  ')

nsala=input('Digite a sala utilizada: ')

ag=input('Digite o nick do Guia (Se não houver digite "X"): ')

obs=input('Digite sua observação da aula')

print('[b]Nick do guia:[/b] [color=#0000ff] [b]WellersonOP [/b] [/color]')

print('[b]Patente e página: [/b] [color=#0000ff] [b]Aspirante [/b] [/color] [color=#ff0000][b][16/12-01][/b][/color]')

print('[b]Data da aula:[/b] [color=#0000ff] [b]{}/{}/{}[/b][/color]'.format(dia, mes, ano))

print(' ')

print('[color=#009900][b]Nick dos aprovados:[/b][/color] [b]{}
[/b]'.format(aprovados))

print('[color=#009900][b]Número de aprovados:[/b][/color] [b]{}[/b]'.format(naprovados))

print('[color=#009900][b]Número de civis:[/b][/color] [b]{}[/b]'.format(nalunos))

print(' ')

print('[color=#ff0000][b]Nick dos reprovados:[/b][/color] [b]{}[/b]'.format(reprovados))

print('[color=#ff0000][b]Número de reprovados:[/b][/color] [b]{}[/b]'.format(nreprovados))

print(' ')

print('[b]Horário de início:[/b] [b]{}[/b]'.format(inicio))

print('[b]Horário de término:[/b] [b]{}[/b]'.format(termino))

print('[b]Número da sala utilizada:[/b] [b]{}[/b]'.format(nsala))

print(' ')

print('[b]A.G:[/b] [b]{}[/b]'.format(ag))

print('[b]Observação:[/b] [b]{}[/b]'.format(obs))

print('[b]Sua assinatura:[/b]')
```

E funciona perfeitamente, porém, queria saber como fazer os dias em vez de aparecer 1/6/2018, aparecer 01/06/2018, mas que não afetar quando fosse 10/11/2018 por exemplo, pois se eu adiciona-se o 0 na frente da print da data, quando eu colocar nessa data, iria aparecer 010/011/2018.
Alguém poderia me dar o comando para isso juntamente da explicação?

Também gostaria de colocar em AG, se ninguém digita-se nada, automaticamente aparecia um texto personalizado, também poderia me explicar isso?

Answer (score 2):

Faça uma concatenação do dia antes de imprimir, onde verifica se o valor impresso é menor ou igual dia "9". Somente valores iguais ou menores  podem receber um "zero" na frente.Os valores de 10 acima (31) continuam normais.(Não sou usuário do Python. Sou usuário de Object Pascal. Verifique detalhes da sintaxe)

```
if dia<=9:dia = str("0" + dia)
```

Answer (score 1):

Na linha que imprime a data, tente desta forma:

```
print('[b]Data da aula:[/b] [color=#0000ff] [b]{}[/b][/color]'.format(now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))
```