# Como, de maneira simples, gerar documentos HTML complexos em python?

Tags: python, template, console-application

> Baseado nessa pergunta: [Duvidas do python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266241/duvidas-do-python)

Na pergunta citada acima o usuário alega estar fazendo um sistema de preenchimento de questionários e deseja que a saída seja *HTML*. Porém o código proposto no MCVE da pergunta:

- Não gera um documento *HTML* e sim um documento num formato conhecido como [BBCode](https://www.bbcode.org/) que é uma linguagem de marcação usada para formatar mensagens em fóruns e blogs.
- O documento gerado é montado de forma artesanal linha a linha com a função [print()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print).

Então para um script que realmente gere um documento *HTML*, um exemplo mínimo completo e verificável seria:

```python
d ={
  "nome": "Augusto Vasques",             #input("Digite o seu nome: "),
  "site": "Stack Overflow em Português", #input("Digite o nome do site: ")
}
html = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>Bem Vindo {d["nome"]}!</h1>

    <p>Esse é o {d["site"]}</p>

</body>

</html>
"""
print(html)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>Bem Vindo Augusto Vasques!</h1>

    <p>Esse é o Stack Overflow em Português</p>

</body>

</html>
```

O código simula a coleta de informações do usuário em um dicionário e a partir de um [fstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) cria, e povoa com os dados desse dicionário, um documento *HTML*.
Para um documento extremamente simples é o suficiente, porém caso sejam exigidas mais opções e detalhamento na entrada de dados o código escalaria em complexidade e propensão a erros, veja o seguinte exemplo:

```python
d ={
  "nome": "Augusto Vasques",             #input("Digite o seu nome: "),
  "site": "Stack Overflow em Português", #input("Digite o nome do site: "),
  "tags": ["c", "c++", "c#", "java", "php"]
}

def listar_tags(l):
  return '\n'.join(
    ["<ul>"] + 
    [f"\t<li>{t}</li>" for t in l] + 
    ["</ul>"])

html = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Bem Vindo {d["nome"]}!</h1>

  <p>Esse é o {d["site"]}</p>
  <p>Essas são algumas de nossas tags:</p>
  {listar_tags(d["tags"])}

</body>

</html>
"""
print(html)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Bem Vindo Augusto Vasques!</h1>

  <p>Esse é o Stack Overflow em Português</p>
  <p>Essas são algumas de nossas tags:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>c++</li>
    <li>c#</li>
    <li>java</li>
    <li>php</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Para uma tarefa simples com adicionar uma lista de tags já se tornou algo mais intrincado.

Frameworks web, como [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) e [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/), possuem uma abordagem bastante conveniente de como gerar *HTML* dinamicamente que é o uso de templates([Templates Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/) e [Templates Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/templates/)).

**Então faço a pergunta**, como em uma aplicação Python de console gerar de maneira simples documentos *HTML* complexos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é importar uma Engine de Templates igual as engines utilizadas em [Frameworks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework) Web.
No caso utilizei a engine [Jinja2](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/) por possuir uma [sintaxe bastante difundida](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/) e ter a [API bem documentada](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/).

O trabalho então foi dividido em criar um modelo para que os valores sejam preenchidos dinamicamente e um script Python para "coletar" e renderizar valores num template:

**modelo.ui**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Bem Vindo {{ nome|e }}!</h1>

  <p>Esse é o {{ site|e }}</p>
  <p>Essas são algumas de nossas tags:</p>
  <ul>
    {% for t in tags %}
    <li>{{ t|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

**main.py**

```python
from jinja2 import Template

d ={
  "nome": "Augusto Vasques",             #input("Digite o seu nome: "),
  "site": "Stack Overflow em Português", #input("Digite o nome do site: "),
  "tags": ["c", "c++", "c#", "java", "php"]
}

#Abre o arquivo contendo o template...
with open("modelo.ui") as f:
  template = Template(f.read())       #...carrega o template.

#Renderiza o template com o valores das chaves em d.
print(template.render(d))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Bem Vindo Augusto Vasques!</h1>

  <p>Esse é o Stack Overflow em Português</p>
  <p>Essas são algumas de nossas tags:</p>
  <ul>
    
    <li>c</li>
    
    <li>c++</li>
    
    <li>c#</li>
    
    <li>java</li>
    
    <li>php</li>
    
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Jinja2Template#main.py)</sup>